# Obscure Java import syntax?

Tags: java, syntax, import

I've come across obscure `import` syntax while looking at [some source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/awt/ComponentFactory.java.html) from Sun's JVM implementation.

```
import java.awt;
```

From a look at the source code, this `import` statement appears to be importing the entire `java.awt` package, but the standard is to use a package wildcard: `import java.awt.*;`.  However, the syntax of the `import` statement in `ComponentFactory` is invalid and does not compile with JDK or Eclipse.

Why would Java developers use this uncompilable syntax used, rather than the correct `.*` syntax?  (Maybe the developers use a different compiler which supports this syntax?)

Comment: I guess source code published is wrongly.

Comment: The file name is `.java.html`. I guess some formatting happened in the html conversion.

Comment: And I looked at some other sources, none of the import statements have `.*` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked at the latest [JLS (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1), it says:

> Example 7.5.1-3. No Import of a Subpackage
>
> Note that an import statement **cannot** import a subpackage, only a type.
>
> For example, it does not work to try to import java.util and then use
>   the name util.Random to refer to the type java.util.Random:
>
> ```
> import java.util;   // incorrect: compile-time error
> class Test { util.Random generator; }
> ```

There is no reason that the language designers are using a different version of Java. They may have some secret tools for coding and testing, they might also test on some new features (but I don't think this is a new feature, as new features shouldn't be released like this without any description)

I believe it is the HTML formatting that automatically eliminates all the `.*` parts of import declarations.

Answer (score 1):

According to [some documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) published by Oracle:

> Note: Another, less common form of import allows you to import the
>   public nested classes of an enclosing class. For example, if the
>   graphics.Rectangle class contained useful nested classes, such as
>   Rectangle.DoubleWide and Rectangle.Square, you could import Rectangle
>   and its nested classes by using the following two statements.
>
> ```
> import graphics.Rectangle;
> import graphics.Rectangle.*;
> ```
>
> Be aware that the second import statement will not import Rectangle.

However, after trying to import `java.awt`, I realized that this is not valid syntax because it is only a package a not a class. This leads me to believe that they published code that simply omits the `.*` after most of its imports to make the code appear slightly cleaner. Regardless, you can't write imports like this.